# Database null pointer exception in android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-sqlite

can you help me with this one. I don't know why I am getting null pointer exception even I know that the data is exist in the database. What I am trying to do is to access a method in a class, that method is for getting all the information of the given report code in the database. But it keeps on giving me null pointer exception. Here is the method I am referring to:

- I am calling the method of different class through this:

  S_9th_ISubmit a = new S_9th_ISubmit();

  a.Uploading();
- This is the method I am calling

  ```
  public void Uploading()
  {

  for (int i = 0; i < Constants.ARRAYLIST_REPORTCODES.size(); i++) 
  {
      Log.d("size:", String.valueOf(Constants.ARRAYLIST_REPORTCODES.size()));
      Log.d("content", String.valueOf(Constants.ARRAYLIST_REPORTCODES));

      final String code = Constants.ARRAYLIST_REPORTCODES.get(i).toString();
      Log.d("Uploading contents of Report Code: ", code);

      Cursor details = databaseHandler.getHeaderDetails(code);


      final String infotype   = details.getString(details.getColumnIndex(Constants.REPORT_INFOTYPECODE));
      String district         = details.getString(details.getColumnIndex(Constants.REPORT_DISTRICTCODE));
      final String province   = details.getString(details.getColumnIndex(Constants.REPORT_PROVINCECODE));
      final String date       = details.getString(details.getColumnIndex(Constants.REPORT_DATEOBSERVED));
      final String competitor = details.getString(details.getColumnIndex(Constants.REPORT_ISCOMPETITOR));
      final String remarks    = details.getString(details.getColumnIndex(Constants.REPORT_REMARKS));
  ```

  }

Do i need to open the database to access the database.?  Below shows my logcat.

```
09-12 08:43:52.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14919): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-12 08:43:52.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14919): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-12 08:43:52.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14919):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
09-12 08:43:52.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14919):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:149)
09-12 08:43:52.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14919):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
09-12 08:43:52.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14919):    at com.dfd.ireport.DatabaseHandler.getHeaderDetails(DatabaseHandler.java:437)
09-12 08:43:52.250: E/AndroidRuntime(14919):    at com.dfd.ireport.S_9th_ISubmit.Uploading(S_9th_ISubmit.java:1137)
```

Here is the code in my databaseHandler

```
public Cursor getHeaderDetails(String code){
    SQLiteDatabase dbSqlite = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = dbSqlite.query(Constants.TABLE_REPORT, new String[] { Constants.REPORT_ID, 
            Constants.REPORT_CODE, 
            Constants.REPORT_INFOTYPECODE, 
            Constants.REPORT_DISTRICTCODE, 
            Constants.REPORT_PROVINCECODE, 
            Constants.REPORT_DATEOBSERVED,
            Constants.REPORT_ISCOMPETITOR, 
            Constants.REPORT_REMARKS}, Constants.REPORT_CODE+"=?", new String[]{code}, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    dbSqlite.close();
    return c;
}
```

I tried to add this on my Uploading method to access the database but nothing happened.What else do I need to do, how can I check the context that I'm getting?

```
 DatabaseHandler databaseHandler;
        databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        if (databaseHandler != null)
        {
            databaseHandler.close();
            databaseHandler.createDB();
        }
```

Comment: What is on line 1137 of S_9th_ISubmit.java?

Comment: show code `DatabaseHandler.getHeaderDetails()`

Comment: this the content of the line 1137 Cursor details = databaseHandler.getHeaderDetails(code);

Comment: what is at line 437 in DatabaseHandler?

Comment: make sure you are not passing `null` to `getHeaderDetails`. Log and see what is `code`

Comment: @Varun line 437 is SQLiteDatabase dbSqlite = this.getReadableDatabase(); yeah, i am sure that code is not null and is exist on the database, but still it returning a null pointer exception

Comment: Please show us the code for S_9th_ISubmit, at least the constructors of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is in `SQLiteDatabase dbSqlite = this.getReadableDatabase();`, dbSqlite is null!
getReadableDatabase() is returning null because you are passing a wrong context.
Try to check the context you are passing.

Comment: Thanks for giving me nice idea. I got an error because of wrong context.

Answer (score 0):

Cursor details = databaseHandler.getHeaderDetails(code) show null point.

The problem is that the databaseHandler is null,you can check it with

```
Cursor details;
if(databaseHandler != null){
    details = databaseHandler.getHeaderDetails(code);
}else{
    Log.e(" databaseHandler : " ," databaseHandler == null");
}
```

if the problem in getHeaderDetails(),logcat will show the the line of code which cause null point exception,but i do not see